# Open source Dock kind of menu in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, menu, dock

I want to create Mac Dock kind of menu for one of my application.

Please let me know, if there is any open source library or code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen them before, but not in a while, I'm surprised Google is turning up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The one I remember from ages ago is the FishEye project.  Not sure the status, but a simple google search gave this result:
http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/components/fisheye-component/

Best of luck,
Jeremy

Comment: Hey Raghu.  What part doesn't work?  Are you using the source or a swc?

Comment: I am using source, as there is no swc file in the download. Main part itself is not working.

Comment: It says, Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed.
Even source does not have the mx tags. I am using flex builder 3.